# Compare List SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
table t1{ida,idb,idc}
```

and I have a list of records in tabletype variable

```
table t2{idb,idc}
```

now, I want to check that doesn't exist any group of `t1` same as all of `t2` where group i by ida

Comment: Please provide some example data and expected output to clarify

Comment: Plus tag database you're using in the question

Comment: I have a table t1(ida,idb,idc) for example with these records:
(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,2),(2,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,1,2)
and a list t2(idb,idc) with these records:
(1,1),(2,1),(3,2)

in this example first i want to group t1 by ida ,then check that t2 exists in grouped t1,
grouped:(1,(1,1),(2,1),(3.2)),(2,(1,1),(2,1),(1,2))

so t2 records exists in grouped list : (1,(1,1),(2,1),(3.2))

Comment: In the question please. Also, tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data as DML statements, and desirec output. It would also be a good idea to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Look at EXCEPT and INTERSECT; or outer joins with null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query which uses `inner join` to find the matching rows in tables `t1` and `t2` and shows `t1.ida` value for which there is a complete match

```
select a.ida
from t1 a inner join t2 b 
on a.idb =  b.idb and a.idc = b.idc
group by a.ida 
having count(1) >= (select count(1) from t2)
```

Comment: tanx,what means of last line?

Comment: This doesn't work: `INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2, 1 ),
        ( 1, 3, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, 2 )` and `INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 ),
    (4, 2)`.

And you are returning `1`

Comment: @user2830448 last line compares the number of matching pairs between tables `t1(idb,idc)` and `t2(idb,idc)` for each value of `t1.ida`

Comment: You can not rely on counts as in table 2 there may be 4 distinct rows and in table 1 there may 4 rows but two of them may be the same.

Comment: @user2830448 check modified query

Comment: @user2830448, are you sure? `INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2, 1 ),
        ( 1, 3, 2 ),
        ( 1, 3, 3 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, 2 )

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 )`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( ida INT, idb INT, idc INT )
DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( idb INT, idc INT )

INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2, 1 ),
        ( 1, 3, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, 2 )

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 )

SELECT DISTINCT
        t1.ida
FROM    @t1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   @t2 t2
                     WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                         FROM   @t1
                                         WHERE  ida = t1.ida
                                                AND idb = t2.idb
                                                AND idc = t2.idc ) )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   @t1 tt1
                         WHERE  ida = t1.ida
                                AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                                 FROM   @t2
                                                 WHERE  idb = tt1.idb
                                                        AND idc = tt1.idc ) )
```

Output:

```
ida
1
```

So this returns only `ida` values for which there is a complete match except of number of same matches. I.e. the following will still match:

```
( 1, 1, 1 ),
( 1, 2, 1 ),
( 1, 3, 2 ),
( 1, 3, 2 )
```

Comment: it's correct , but is this query expensive cause of much select?